# Mac Address c++ osx

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, ethernet

I need to have access to my `mac address` using `C++`. I've already found some source codes but they're all in `objective-c` or `C#`.
Is that possible to make? My environment is `osx` using `xcode`.

Thanks!

[UPDATE]

I've found this code:
[Get Mac Address C++](http://cs.williams.edu/~morgan/code/C++/getip.cpp)

It works both on OSX and Linux. Thanks!

Comment: You can have any number of MAC addresses, since you can have any number of network interfaces. For instance WLAN vs wired, vs USB wired, and so on. My point is that this is slighly more complicated than you seem to think, you're going to have to decide *which* MAC address you want.

Comment: I want something like this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) (click on download sample code). That code works fine and gives me exactly what i want, but is `C`.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
FILE *fp = popen("ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}'", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%s", &mac);
pclose(fp);
```